# If...else and loop in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

Do we have any option to implement if...else and loop option in Spring Integration xml based configuration? I know these kind of option available in camel (camel:loop & camel:filter), expecting same options in Spring Integration.

**Update 1:-**
Now we are migrating to Spring integration from Apache camel, earlier complete route (Channel in spring integration) has been iterated using camel:loop component, I tried to implement same in spring integration as follows,

```
<int:gateway id="restGateWay"
        service-interface="com.example.springintegration.rest.amqp.Gateway"
        default-request-channel="restInputChannel"
        default-reply-channel="messageProcessedChannel"/>

    <int:chain id="restInputChain"
        input-channel="restInputChannel"
        output-channel="messageProcessedChannel">
        <int:gateway request-channel="iterationChannel"/> 
    </int:chain>

    <int:outbound-channel-adapter id="iterationChannel" method="iterator" 
            ref="integrationRouter">
                <int:poller fixed-rate="10"/>
    </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

But got error as
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A poller should not be specified for endpoint 'validationChannel.adapter', since 'validationChannel' is a SubscribableChannel (not pollable).

Comment: There are many ways to connect components, filter things etc. in Spring Integration. What is most appropriate for your situation depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve, and without knowing any details about your project it's hard to say what would be best for your project.

Comment: My requirement is, in some cases same message needs to send to same channel multiple times. Could you suggest some component to achieve this?

Comment: You can do this with routers and filters, for example. Making a loop is no different from sending messages to any other channel. See documentation: [message routing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#messaging-routing-chapter).

Comment: We need much more info about your use-case. Maybe there is really no need to seek for some *loop* in Spring Integration if you simply can use a pure Java constructions for iteration, even if in the end you send something to `gateway` for Spring Integration flow.

Comment: Thank you for all your reply, really apologies for late in reply. I have added more details in **Update 1**